# Form submit using bootstrap modal without jquery and display event in calendar

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-modal, form-submit

I have successfully submitted form using bootstrap modal in laravel.Now I want to display the data in the calendar according to date.I have tried but unable to get the event in the calendar days.

event.blade.php

```
    css
<link href="{{asset('admin-panel/assets/libs/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{asset('admin-panel/assets/extra-libs/calendar/calendar.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="{{asset('admin-panel/dist/css/style.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{asset('admin-panel/assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>

     <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 border-right p-r-0">
                                <div class="card-body border-bottom">
                                    <h4 class="card-title m-t-10">Drag & Drop Event</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div id="calendar-events" class="">
                                                <div class="calendar-events m-b-20" data-class="bg-info"><i class="fa fa-circle text-info m-r-10"></i>Event</div>
                                                <div class="calendar-events m-b-20" data-class="bg-success"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success m-r-10"></i>Event</div>
                                                <div class="calendar-events m-b-20" data-class="bg-danger"><i class="fa fa-circle text-danger m-r-10"></i>Event</div>
                                                <div class="calendar-events m-b-20" data-class="bg-warning"><i class="fa fa-circle text-warning m-r-10"></i>Event</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- checkbox -->
                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="drop-remove">
                                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="drop-remove">Remove after drop</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-new-event" class="btn m-t-20 btn-info btn-block waves-effect waves-light">
                                                <i class="ti-plus"></i> Add New Event
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <div class="card-body b-l calender-sidebar">
                                    <div id="calendar"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- BEGIN MODAL -->
        <div class="modal none-border" id="my-event">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Add Event</strong></h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body"></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-event waves-effect waves-light">Create event</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-event waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal Add Category -->
        <div class="modal fade none-border" id="add-new-event">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Add</strong> Event</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <form action="{{route('event.store')}}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                    <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class="control-label">Date</label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-white" name="date" type="date"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class="control-label">Event Name</label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-white" name="event" placeholder="Enter name" type="text"/>
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-white" name="description" placeholder="Enter description" type="text"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light save-category">Save</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript

```
    @section('js')

<script src="{{asset('admin-panel/assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('admin-panel/dist/js/jquery-ui.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('admin-panel/assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('admin-panel/dist/js/custom.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('admin-panel/assets/libs/moment/min/moment.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('admin-panel/assets/libs/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('admin-panel/dist/js/pages/calendar/cal-init.js')}}"></script>

    @endsection
```

EventController.php

```
    public function event()
{
    $events=$this->getEventbyMonth(date('m'));
  //        dd($events);
    return view('admin.calendar.event',compact('events'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
 //        dd($request->all);
    $request -> validate([
        'date' => 'required',
        'event' => 'required',
    ]);
    $event = new Event();
    $event -> date = $request -> date;
    $event -> event = $request -> event;
    $event -> description = $request -> description;
    $event ->save();
    return redirect()->route('event');
}

private function getEventbyMonth($month)
{
    return Event::whereMonth('date',$month)->get();
}
```

and my route look like this:

```
     Route::get('event', ['as'=>'event', 'uses' => 'EventController@event']);
     Route::post('event/store, ', ['as'=>'event.store', 'uses' => 'EventController@store']);
```

Expected results:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxLxG.png)

Actual results:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdkuZ.png)

Database:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC58Z.png)

Event form after clicking add new event

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YC4u.png)

Comment: Add the relevant part of your Javascript, I can't see where you fetch the data from your database and add it to the calendar!!!

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki yeah i have updated the question. You can check once. Code will be too long so i have mentioned only limited code.

Comment: You expect to find 2 events in the calendar, but I can't see you adding them, so why you expect that? If you can't show us your attempt, we can't help.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki i have tried and updated in controller section.But how to pass from blade file.Please help me it ruined my whole day.

Comment: I think you're in the right way right now, you're passing the events to the blade, now you need to parse them inside your calendar to display the events... check this tutorial, it may help (https://quickadminpanel.com/blog/laravel-fullcalendar-edit-events-with-bootstrap-modal/)